# message: `Schema hasn't been registered for model "User".\n` + 'Use mongoose.model(name, schema)', name: 'MissingSchemaError'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to create a schema for a user authentication system but keep getting the above error message. I've created two new pages with the following code:

**Users.js**

```
var mongoose = require ('mongoose');
var crypto = require ('crypto');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email:{
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    hash: String,
    salt: String
});

userSchema.methods.setPassword = function(password){
    this.salt = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
    this.hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000, 64).toString('hex');
};
//when the setPassword method is called and supplied with a password, the salt and hash will be generated
//for users and added to the model instance - password is never saved anywhere, and not even stored in memory

userSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password){
    var hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000, 64).toString('hex');
    return this.hash === hash;
};

userSchema.methods.generateJwt = function(){
    var expiry = new Date();
    expiry.setDate(expiry.getDate() + 7);

    return jwt.sign({
        _id: this._id,
        email: this.email,
        name: this.name,
        exp: parseInt(expiry.getTime() / 1000),
    }, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
};

/*var User = mongoose.model('user');
var user = new User();
user.name = "User's name";
user.email = "test@example.com";
user.setPassword("myPassword");
user.save();*/
```

**authentication.js**

```
var passport = require('passport');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = mongoose.model('User');

var sendJSONreponse = function(res, status, content) {
    res.status(status);
    res.json(content);
};

//register controller for the API
module.exports.register = function(req, res){
    if(!req.body.name || !req.body.email || !req.body.password){
        sendJSONreponse(res, 400, {
            "message": "All fields required"
        });
        return;
    }
    var user = new User();
    user.name = req.body.name;
    user.email = req.body.email;

    user.setPassword(req.body.password);

    user.save(function(err) {
        var token;
        if (err){
            sendJSONreponse(res, 404, err);
        } else{
            token = user.generateJwt();
            sendJSONreponse(res, 200, {
                "token" : token
            });
        }
    });
};

//Login controller for the API
module.exports.login = function(req, res) {
    if(!req.body.email || !req.body.password){
        sendJSONreponse (res, 400, {
            "message" : "All fields required"
        });
        return;
    }
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info){
        var token;

        if (err){
            sendJSONreponse(res, 404, err);
            return;
        }
        if(user){
            token = user.generateJwt();
            sendJSONreponse(res, 200, {
                "token" : token
            });
        } else {
            sendJSONreponse(res, 401, info);
        }
    }) (req, res);
};


module.exports = router;
```

**app.js** This is some of the code which relates to the above

```
require('dotenv');
var express = require('express');
var createError = require('http-errors');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var uglifyJS = require("uglify-js");
var fs = require ('fs');
var passport = require('passport');
//require('./app_api/models/blogModel');

require('./app_api/models/db');
require('./app_api/config/passport');

var routesApi = require('./app_api/routes/index');

var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var mongoDB = "mongodb://**********************************;
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(mongoDB, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
.then(() =>  console.log('connection successful'))
.catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

```
/*BRING IN SCHEMAS AND MODELS*/
require('./users');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.use(express.static('public')); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ 
    extended: true
}));
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'app_server', 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'app_client')));

app.use(passport.initialize());

app.use('/api', routesApi);



//make db accessible to router
// app.use(function(req, res, next){
//   req.db=db;
//   next();
// });
```

```
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

// catch unauthorised errors
app.use(function (err, req, res, next){
  if (err.name === 'UnauthorizedError'){
    res.status(401);
    res.json({"message" : err.name + ": " + err.message});
  }
});

module.exports = app;
```

I've been following a textbook and the formatting etc. is correct; I just don't know where the error is coming from.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the bottom of Users you need to declare the model, using `mongoose.model('Users',userSchema);` also export it, you then interact with the model, schema is more of a declaration (details), the model is the implementation providing the functionality you're requiring.

You actually were pretty close, you needed to add the schema argument to the model.